# Kivy : Run .py file onclick on image

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## demo.Kv

```
AsyncImage:
            canvas:
                Rectangle:
                    texture: CoreImage("add.jpg").texture
                    size: self.width, self.height
                    size: 30, 30
                    pos: self.x - 1, self.y
                    #on_release: os.system("python test.py")
```

Can anyone help me?
 1. This code is in my .kv file. How to run test.py file onclick on add.jpg image.
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1):

so somewhere relevant in your main.py probably the root(class) file write a function that will run the test.py like this

```
def run_test():
    os.system('python file.py')
```

and do import the os module. Now replace this with what you have in your kv file

```
on_release: root.run_test()
```

Comment: you need a custom widget, @sp-sp has provided a nice way of doing that above

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom widget:

**.py**:

```
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
import os


MyAsyncImage(AsyncImage)

    #other stuff

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            os.system('python file.py')
```

Then in your .kv:

```
MyAsyncImage:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            texture: CoreImage("add.jpg").texture
            size: self.width, self.height
            size: 30, 30
            pos: self.x - 1, self.y
```